# How does this Bash script work?

Tags: regex, bash

```
read -r -p "Are you sure? [y/N] " response
 if [[ "$response" =~ ^([yY][eE][sS]|[yY])+$ ]]
then
 do_something
else
 do_something_else
fi
```

I saw this script on a stack overflow website I used the following script because I couldn't write one myself because it threw errors. I know this script will wait for user input such as y/n but I would like detailed explanation about how this script works like what does `=~` do and what does `^([yY][eE][sS]|[yY])+$ ]]` do.

Comment: Can you copy the explanation from `man bash` and explain what's not clear about it?

Comment: Are you sure you understand the "[ operand"?  I ask because `[` is not an operator, and it seems very odd to use the phrase "[ operand". Also, this script doesn't use `[`.  It uses `[[`, which is a very different thing.

Comment: @William Pursell Oh I thought the `[` and `[[` are same thanks for the explanation by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if [[ "$response" =~ ^([yY][eE][sS]|[yY])+$ ]]
```

The `[[ ]]` is a bashism testing statement, similar to `[ ]` but with a few differences. More detail is available in `man bash`.

The `=~` does RegEx matching, and

```
^([yY][eE][sS]|[yY])+$
```

is a regular expression, standing for **One or more combinations of `y` and `yes`, case-insensitive**.

It actually tests if the user's input is `y`, `Yes`, `yES`, `YyyY` or `YyyYYesyesyes` (or anything else that matches the given RegEx).

From `man 1 bash`:

> An additional binary operator, =~, is available, with the same precedence as == and !=.  When it is used, the string to the right of the operator is considered an **extended regular expression** and matched accordingly (as in `regex(3)`).

> #### [[ expression ]]
>
> Return a status of 0 or 1 depending on the evaluation of the conditional expression expression.

Comment: I use this idiom extensively in my scripts, but I've found it's much simpler to use `if [[ "${response^^}" =~ ^Y(ES)?$ ]]`. The `^^` is a bashism that converts the string to upper case, which makes it a whole lot easier to write a regex for.

Comment: @MikeHolt Freaking useful! Thank you for that idea about `^^`.

Comment: @iBug yes I want to do that but it says wait for 3 min ;(

Comment: @iBug Could you explain what the `+` near the end does, please?

Comment: @leetbacoon RegEx `+` means "repeat one or more times" and is equivalent to `{1,}`.

Comment: @iBug Thanks! Do you know about the `?` in Mike's answer?

Comment: @leetbacoon I recommend you to take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22937618/5958455) and maybe bookmark it for further references.